# Create LINQ Association without Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, linq, foreign-keys

Is it possible to have something like ContactAddress.Contact in LINQ without creating a foreign key relationship in SQL Server between those two (which would be Contact.Id <-> ContactAddress.ContactId)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a relationship in your Object-Relational Map (even when that relationship doesn't exist in the database as a declared foreign key), then you can do so using the Object-Relational designer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you may define foreign keys that do not exist in the target database. The joins generated by LINQ to SQL will end up the same, by which I mean this:

```
from category in db.Categories
from product in category.Products
select new
{
    Category = category,
    Product = product
}
```

will generate the same T-SQL as this:

```
from category in db.Categories
join product in db.Products on category.CategoryId equals product.CategoryId
select new
{
    Category = category,
    Product = product
}
```

which would be this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Category INNER JOIN Product ON Category.CategoryId = Product.CategoryId
```

This is a useful technique to make legacy schemas more usable.