# How do I use Join instead of Include to query the data in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have Two Tabel. Just like **Teachers** And **Students**. They have a 1 to many relationship

The Two Class Like:

```
public class TTeachers
{  
   [Key]
   public long Id {get; set;}
   public string? No { get; set; }
   public string? Name { get; set; }
}
public class TTStudent
{
   [Key]
   public long Id {get; set;}
   public string? TeacherNo{ get; set; }
   public string? Name{ get; set; }
}
```

For some reason I didn't specify their foreign key.

But The student table has one field, for example teacherNo.Specifies their relationship

Now I want to use Linq to query Teacher And Student If I use foreign key. I just use Include to query Student.
for example:

```
var data = (from t in _context.TTeachers.Include(s=> t.Students)
            where t.ID == ID 
            selet new {
             t.ID ,
             t.Name,
             t.Students,
            }).First();
```

So What's the equivalent use Join ?
I try to this:

```
var data = from t in _context.TTeachers
           join s in _context.TTStudent on t.No equals s.TeacherNo into student
           where t.ID == ID
           select new { t.Name, list = students }
```

It will run with an error.

How can I use Join to query Teacher info and Associated student data？

I mean no navigation properties.My team doesn't allow us to use foreign keys.

Comment: add `teacher`and `student` classes

Comment: @Mernayi This Link is Current Page

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh try to use class select data?

Comment: Add the classes to your question so I can help you

Comment: Excuse me, did not know  what went wrong there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961294/create-linq-association-without-foreign-keys

Comment: Remove `Include` from first query and you will find that `Include` is not needed. Second query is wrong way. Use navigation properties instead.

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh Give me a second

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for the correction. I was wondering if there's a way to do it without navigation properties

Comment: In your queries, where does `a` comes from? None of your code will compile. (what is `s=> t.Students`?)

Comment: @NetMage my mistake. modified

Comment: The whole point of navigation properties is so you *don't* need to use joins. Imagine if you later decide to change the database foreign key, and you had explicit joins everywhere in your code....

Comment: You have conflicting tags: entity-framework and entity-framework-core. What framework and version are you using? Also, your code still won't compile as it has multiple errors.

Comment: @NetMage this code is just for presentation purposes, it doesn't run directly. I use EF Core, I will delete entity-framework tag, Thank you.

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question when it won't even compile. Making sure your code is correct is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupJoin` has limitations with EF Core, better to do that via subquery:

```cs
var data = 
    from t in _context.TTeachers
    where a.Fid == lFid
    select new 
    { 
        t.name,
        list = _context.TTStudent.Where(s => s.TeacherNo == t.No) 
    }
```

Anyway, better to use navigation properties, it has less risk that you have defined wrong compare keys.

Comment: Thank You. I've never done that before. I'm going to try