# Linq - Join into group and select group

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a simple linq query:

```
var ordersList = (from salesOrder in context.SalesOrders
where salesOrder.date >= fromDate && salesOrder.date <= thruDate
join orderJoin in context.Orders on salesOrder.id equals orderJoin.id into orderGroup
select new
{
    OrderGroup = orderGroup
}).ToList();
```

but I'm getting could not be translated error. How can I join into a group and select that group?

Comment: I want to select a group of orders for every salesOrder. The way you're saying it would be a single order for every salesOrder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Join instead of Include to query the data in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136350/how-do-i-use-join-instead-of-include-to-query-the-data-in-ef-core)